# C# Array data transfer to ushort[]

Tags: c#, arrays, ushort

I wrote a method to get data which looks like:

```
public void DatagridToArray(Array registersArray)
{ 
    registersArray = myModulesList.OrderBy(mod => mod.Address).Select(mod => mod.ParamValue).ToArray();
}
```

Now in my usage, I need the data as ushort[], so I declare a variable:

```
public static ushort[] registers = new ushort[20];
```

when I call this method in the following way:

```
this.DatagridToArray(registers);
```

the **Result** when I **Monitor** the `DatagridToArray()` my `registersArray` can get a `int[7]` data, but after the **call**, the `registers` variable turn out to be all `0`. Please tell me how to do with it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the *local* reference of `registersArray`.

Your code should look like this:

```
public ushort[] DatagridToArray()
{ 
    return myModulesList.OrderBy(mod => mod.Address).Select(mod => mod.ParamValue).ToArray();
}
```

And then used like:

```
registers = this.DatagridToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: what if my `myModulesList` is **type** `DataSet`, How I suppose to rewrite the method `DatagridToArray()`?